# AWS EMR Python process is abnormally exited error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

When I trying to run the following code in AWS EMR Zeppelin with Spark:

```
%spark.pyspark
knn_imputer = KNNImputer()
pre_stage_1.iloc[:, :] = knn_imputer.fit_transform(pre_stage_1.toPandas())
```

I got the following error:

```
Python process is abnormally exited, please check your code and log.
```

pre_stage_1 is a dataset with about 1000000 rows.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the stracktrace that led the process to exit or upload the log somewhere and link it here. This is a blind shot in the dark, but I would check the memory size of the executors and how much is allocated for Python to use. This might be a OOM. Often yarn/ scheduler will auto terminate process that consumes all the memory.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error recently, and was fixed by restarting the Spark Interpreter.

(to debug, I commented out my original code and just tried to `print('hi')`, which gave the same error, so I knew it wasn't a problem with the code I was trying to run)